# How to use object variable as a global/public variable Android

Tags: android, variables, object, webview, global

exi want to load an url in mywebview when the end-user click on 'item1' in the option menu

Here is my code :

```
package com.exemple.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                //AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                //alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
                //alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                //alertDialog.show();
                myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.google.com");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: The question title and content don't match up.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

to

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

And add the following as a class variable:

```
WebView myWebView;
```

So your final code becomes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.google.info"); //You may want to comment this out, as you said you wanted to load it only when the user clicked
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                //AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                //alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
                //alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                //alertDialog.show();
                myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.google.com");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer but can you be more precise, can you modify my code :) im a complety beginnier !